# Excel if two cells are identical fill third cell

Tags: excel

i haven't been able to solve this issue in the past hour so i'm trying to find help here.

i have 2 colums with dates: one with every date from 01.01.18 to 31.12.22 and one with specific dates where something of interest happened, which is in the column next to it. My goal is to end up with 2 column, one with all dates and one with the events put in. if nothing happened between dates i want the previous event to carry over until a new event happened.

This probably sounds more complicated than it is. I feel the solution should be obvious but i can't wrap my head around it. these Screenshots should help explain the task:

```
=IF(D12:D576=A12:A1897;E12:E576;0)
```

red part is supposed to be filled with information from the 2nd imagine

[image]

ideally for every date without a value i'd want the value from the previous date to carry over

[image]

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: I didn't understand your problem at all but looking at your formula sounds like you may benefit from COUNTIFS to count if a date appears or not and then return 0 or something else...

Comment: My goal was to end up with 2 colums total: 1 with all dates from 01.01.18 to 31.12.22, the second one filled with values. from the example images. so from the images the dates "03.01 to 05.01" should contain the value "6", the dates "06.01 to 09.01" should contain value 10 and so on.

Sorry if the question was unclear, english is not my native language and i had to translate the formulas into english aswell

Answer (score 1):

At first it was hard to understand, but after your comment I think I get it.
You can use `VLOOKUP` with approximate match (`TRUE`) if your dates are sorted ascending:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1,$E$1:$F$6,2,TRUE),0)
```

Drop it in `B1` and drag it down or use `=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A1:A20,$E$1:$F$6,2,TRUE),0)` to fill all column at once.

Result:

[image]

With second formula:

[image]

Adapt ranges to your data.

Comment: Thank you so, so much for sticking around even with a poor explanation. I tried your first formula and it worked like a charm. I assume the second one works aswell as i noticed the mistake i was doing by looking at your solution!